# How to recursively `dir()` an object in Python 3.9.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this has been asked many times, but I am using Python 3.9.5 and none of the solutions I have found here have worked.

My request is very simple: getting an XML tree list of names of all available objects of an object and its subobjects.

To illustrate this, I have installed many Python modules and would like to know everything a module offers.

`dir()` method returns a list of names of attributes inside an object, it returns a list of strings.

`type()` method returns the type of an object, some subobjects have subobjects themselves, and I want an XML tree listing all the names (and only names, not values) of the lowest level objects, that is, objects that are of types `int`, `bool`, `float`, `str`, `set`, `list`, `tuple`, `dict` etc.

For example, consider we have an object named `obj`, obj has three attributes: `a`, `b` and `c`. `a` doesn't have unique attributes, `b` has two unique attributes: `d` and `e`, and `d` and `e` don't have unique attributes, `c` has three unique attributes: `f`, `g` and `h`, and `f` has a unique attribute named `i`, `g` has a unique attribute named `j`, and `h` has a unique attribute named `k`. `i`, `j` and `k` are of builtin types.

Now the result should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<elem name='obj'>
    <attr name='a' />
    <elem name='obj.b'>
        <attr name='d' />
        <attr name='e' />
    </elem>
    <elem name='obj.c'>
        <elem name='obj.c.f'>
            <attr name='i' />
        </elem>
        <elem name='obj.c.g'>
            <attr name='j' />
        </elem>
        <elem name='obj.c.h'>
            <attr name='k' />
        </elem>
    </elem>
</elem>
```

The elements marked with `elem` are custom classes that have `__dict__` attributes, and the elements marked with `attr` don't have `__dict__`s.

Now to get attributes of `obj`, we use `dir(obj)` and it returns a list of strings `['a','b','c']`.

To get attributes of `obj.c` we have to type `dir(obj.c)` manually, because `'c'` is a string and `'obj.c'` is not in `vars()`.

Now to convert string to name we have to use `eval()`. `dir(eval('obj.c'))` executes correctly.

But to use the command recursively we have to use something like this:

```
dir(eval(f'{obj.__name__}.{attr}'))
```

But the `__name__` attribute doesn't give its fullname (like `obj.c.f`), and if the name contains `__` the `__name__` value will not have `__`s. Not to mention some objects don't have a `__name__` attribute.

So how can this be done?

---

### ***Update***

I have made some initial success:

```py
import inspect
from xml.dom.minidom import Document

doc = Document()

def treeobj(obj, path=''):
    fullname = f'{path}.{obj.__name__}'.lstrip('.')
    node = doc.createElement('elem')
    node.setAttribute('name', fullname)
    for attr in dir(obj):
        if not attr.startswith('__'):
            val = getattr(obj, attr)
            if inspect.isclass(val):
                elem = treeobj(val, fullname)
            else:
                elem = doc.createElement('attr')
                elem.setAttribute('name', attr)
            node.appendChild(elem)
    return node
```

This is the output of `print(treeobj(os).toprettyxml())`:

```
<elem name="os">
        <elem name="os.DirEntry">
                <attr name="inode"/>
                <attr name="is_dir"/>
                <attr name="is_file"/>
                <attr name="is_symlink"/>
                <attr name="name"/>
                <attr name="path"/>
                <attr name="stat"/>
        </elem>
        <attr name="F_OK"/>
        <elem name="os.GenericAlias"/>
        <elem name="os.Mapping">
                <attr name="_abc_impl"/>
                <attr name="get"/>
                <attr name="items"/>
                <attr name="keys"/>
                <attr name="values"/>
        </elem>
        <elem name="os.MutableMapping">
                <attr name="_MutableMapping__marker"/>
                <attr name="_abc_impl"/>
                <attr name="clear"/>
                <attr name="get"/>
                <attr name="items"/>
                <attr name="keys"/>
                <attr name="pop"/>
                <attr name="popitem"/>
                <attr name="setdefault"/>
                <attr name="update"/>
                <attr name="values"/>
        </elem>
        <attr name="O_APPEND"/>
        <attr name="O_BINARY"/>
        <attr name="O_CREAT"/>
        <attr name="O_EXCL"/>
        <attr name="O_NOINHERIT"/>
        <attr name="O_RANDOM"/>
        <attr name="O_RDONLY"/>
        <attr name="O_RDWR"/>
        <attr name="O_SEQUENTIAL"/>
        <attr name="O_SHORT_LIVED"/>
        <attr name="O_TEMPORARY"/>
        <attr name="O_TEXT"/>
        <attr name="O_TRUNC"/>
        <attr name="O_WRONLY"/>
        <attr name="P_DETACH"/>
        <attr name="P_NOWAIT"/>
        <attr name="P_NOWAITO"/>
        <attr name="P_OVERLAY"/>
        <attr name="P_WAIT"/>
        <elem name="os.PathLike">
                <attr name="_abc_impl"/>
        </elem>
        <attr name="R_OK"/>
        <attr name="SEEK_CUR"/>
        <attr name="SEEK_END"/>
        <attr name="SEEK_SET"/>
        <attr name="TMP_MAX"/>
        <attr name="W_OK"/>
        <attr name="X_OK"/>
        <elem name="os._AddedDllDirectory">
                <attr name="close"/>
        </elem>
        <elem name="os._Environ">
                <attr name="_MutableMapping__marker"/>
                <attr name="_abc_impl"/>
                <attr name="clear"/>
                <attr name="copy"/>
                <attr name="get"/>
                <attr name="items"/>
                <attr name="keys"/>
                <attr name="pop"/>
                <attr name="popitem"/>
                <attr name="setdefault"/>
                <attr name="update"/>
                <attr name="values"/>
        </elem>
        <attr name="_check_methods"/>
        <attr name="_execvpe"/>
        <attr name="_exists"/>
        <attr name="_exit"/>
        <attr name="_fspath"/>
        <attr name="_get_exports_list"/>
        <attr name="_walk"/>
        <elem name="os._wrap_close">
                <attr name="close"/>
        </elem>
        <attr name="abc"/>
        <attr name="abort"/>
        <attr name="access"/>
        <attr name="add_dll_directory"/>
        <attr name="altsep"/>
        <attr name="chdir"/>
        <attr name="chmod"/>
        <attr name="close"/>
        <attr name="closerange"/>
        <attr name="cpu_count"/>
        <attr name="curdir"/>
        <attr name="defpath"/>
        <attr name="device_encoding"/>
        <attr name="devnull"/>
        <attr name="dup"/>
        <attr name="dup2"/>
        <attr name="environ"/>
        <elem name="os.OSError">
                <attr name="args"/>
                <attr name="characters_written"/>
                <attr name="errno"/>
                <attr name="filename"/>
                <attr name="filename2"/>
                <attr name="strerror"/>
                <attr name="winerror"/>
                <attr name="with_traceback"/>
        </elem>
        <attr name="execl"/>
        <attr name="execle"/>
        <attr name="execlp"/>
        <attr name="execlpe"/>
        <attr name="execv"/>
        <attr name="execve"/>
        <attr name="execvp"/>
        <attr name="execvpe"/>
        <attr name="extsep"/>
        <attr name="fdopen"/>
        <attr name="fsdecode"/>
        <attr name="fsencode"/>
        <attr name="fspath"/>
        <attr name="fstat"/>
        <attr name="fsync"/>
        <attr name="ftruncate"/>
        <attr name="get_exec_path"/>
        <attr name="get_handle_inheritable"/>
        <attr name="get_inheritable"/>
        <attr name="get_terminal_size"/>
        <attr name="getcwd"/>
        <attr name="getcwdb"/>
        <attr name="getenv"/>
        <attr name="getlogin"/>
        <attr name="getpid"/>
        <attr name="getppid"/>
        <attr name="isatty"/>
        <attr name="kill"/>
        <attr name="linesep"/>
        <attr name="link"/>
        <attr name="listdir"/>
        <attr name="lseek"/>
        <attr name="lstat"/>
        <attr name="makedirs"/>
        <attr name="mkdir"/>
        <attr name="name"/>
        <attr name="open"/>
        <attr name="pardir"/>
        <attr name="path"/>
        <attr name="pathsep"/>
        <attr name="pipe"/>
        <attr name="popen"/>
        <attr name="putenv"/>
        <attr name="read"/>
        <attr name="readlink"/>
        <attr name="remove"/>
        <attr name="removedirs"/>
        <attr name="rename"/>
        <attr name="renames"/>
        <attr name="replace"/>
        <attr name="rmdir"/>
        <attr name="scandir"/>
        <attr name="sep"/>
        <attr name="set_handle_inheritable"/>
        <attr name="set_inheritable"/>
        <attr name="spawnl"/>
        <attr name="spawnle"/>
        <attr name="spawnv"/>
        <attr name="spawnve"/>
        <attr name="st"/>
        <attr name="startfile"/>
        <attr name="stat"/>
        <elem name="os.stat_result">
                <attr name="count"/>
                <attr name="index"/>
                <attr name="n_fields"/>
                <attr name="n_sequence_fields"/>
                <attr name="n_unnamed_fields"/>
                <attr name="st_atime"/>
                <attr name="st_atime_ns"/>
                <attr name="st_ctime"/>
                <attr name="st_ctime_ns"/>
                <attr name="st_dev"/>
                <attr name="st_file_attributes"/>
                <attr name="st_gid"/>
                <attr name="st_ino"/>
                <attr name="st_mode"/>
                <attr name="st_mtime"/>
                <attr name="st_mtime_ns"/>
                <attr name="st_nlink"/>
                <attr name="st_reparse_tag"/>
                <attr name="st_size"/>
                <attr name="st_uid"/>
        </elem>
        <elem name="os.statvfs_result">
                <attr name="count"/>
                <attr name="f_bavail"/>
                <attr name="f_bfree"/>
                <attr name="f_blocks"/>
                <attr name="f_bsize"/>
                <attr name="f_favail"/>
                <attr name="f_ffree"/>
                <attr name="f_files"/>
                <attr name="f_flag"/>
                <attr name="f_frsize"/>
                <attr name="f_fsid"/>
                <attr name="f_namemax"/>
                <attr name="index"/>
                <attr name="n_fields"/>
                <attr name="n_sequence_fields"/>
                <attr name="n_unnamed_fields"/>
        </elem>
        <attr name="strerror"/>
        <attr name="supports_bytes_environ"/>
        <attr name="supports_dir_fd"/>
        <attr name="supports_effective_ids"/>
        <attr name="supports_fd"/>
        <attr name="supports_follow_symlinks"/>
        <attr name="symlink"/>
        <attr name="sys"/>
        <attr name="system"/>
        <elem name="os.terminal_size">
                <attr name="columns"/>
                <attr name="count"/>
                <attr name="index"/>
                <attr name="lines"/>
                <attr name="n_fields"/>
                <attr name="n_sequence_fields"/>
                <attr name="n_unnamed_fields"/>
        </elem>
        <attr name="times"/>
        <elem name="os.times_result">
                <attr name="children_system"/>
                <attr name="children_user"/>
                <attr name="count"/>
                <attr name="elapsed"/>
                <attr name="index"/>
                <attr name="n_fields"/>
                <attr name="n_sequence_fields"/>
                <attr name="n_unnamed_fields"/>
                <attr name="system"/>
                <attr name="user"/>
        </elem>
        <attr name="truncate"/>
        <attr name="umask"/>
        <elem name="os.uname_result">
                <attr name="count"/>
                <attr name="index"/>
                <attr name="machine"/>
                <attr name="n_fields"/>
                <attr name="n_sequence_fields"/>
                <attr name="n_unnamed_fields"/>
                <attr name="nodename"/>
                <attr name="release"/>
                <attr name="sysname"/>
                <attr name="version"/>
        </elem>
        <attr name="unlink"/>
        <attr name="unsetenv"/>
        <attr name="urandom"/>
        <attr name="utime"/>
        <attr name="waitpid"/>
        <attr name="waitstatus_to_exitcode"/>
        <attr name="walk"/>
        <attr name="write"/>
</elem>
```

However there doesn't seem to be nested classes with depth more than 1, so I don't know if my code is working or not for sure, but the code doesn't throw errors here.

But `treeobj(PyQt6.QtCore)` throws errors:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in treeobj
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in treeobj
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in treeobj
AttributeError: 'TimerInfo' object attribute 'interval' is an instance attribute
```

How can I fix my code?

---

The error should be generated when getattr() function accesses interval attribute of PyQt6.QtCore.QAbstractEventDispatcher.TimerInfo object, which is an instance attribute and not supported by getattr(), thus an error is generated.

What is instance attribute and how to get values of "normal attribute" and instance attributes alike?

Comment: Don't use eval, use [`*attr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) functions for object attribute manipulation and [`literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#literal_eval) for code/structure evaluation.

Comment: It would be more useful to provide concrete Python code that would construct your object that produced your XML output; I can tell you that [nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173362) will provide the `.` notation you want (through `__qualname__`).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I have just fixed my code. It is now working as intended. Though it is still basic, it is functioning.

The things I wanted to find are class attributes, these attributes are shared by every object by the same class.

Class attributes don't usually change, and they shouldn't change, but if they change the change will affect every object of the same class.

Instance attributes are unique to each object, they are declared in the `__init__` function, they are defined when the object is created and their change in one instance will not affect other objects of the same class.

`getattr` can only get class attributes, because class attributes are shared by all objects of the same class and are predefined whereas instance attributes are unique to each object and not defined before the object's creation.

`dir()` method usually calls the `__dir__()` method of a class, which returns a list of names of the attributes inside a class as strings, making it a little difficult to access the attribute of the class using its return value programmatically.

However most classes have a `__dict__` attribute, which is a dictionary of the first level attributes of the class, with the names of the attributes in strings as keys, like what `dir()` returns, but the keys have actual references to the respective objects as values, making it easy to access the object from the keys.

Here is the code:

```py
import importlib
import inspect
import sys
from xml.dom.minidom import Document

doc = Document()

def treeobj(obj, path=''):
    fullname = f'{path}.{obj.__name__}'.lstrip('.')
    node = doc.createElement('class')
    node.setAttribute('name', fullname)
    for attr in obj.__dict__.keys():
        if not attr.startswith('__'):
            val = obj.__dict__[attr]
            if inspect.isclass(val):
                elem = treeobj(val, fullname)
            else:
                elem = doc.createElement('attr')
                elem.setAttribute('name', attr)
            node.appendChild(elem)
    return node

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = importlib.import_module(sys.argv[1])
    doc.appendChild(treeobj(obj))
    print(doc.toprettyxml())
```